# Bootstrap datepicker options not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a form field that is a date and I'm using datepicker for that. This is the form field:

```
<div class=form-group>
  <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
    <input class="form-control" id="data" name="data" placeholder="VVVV/MM/DD" type="text" />
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

These are the options I have provided which are not being applied:

```
$('#data').datepicker({
  format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
  todayHighlight: true,
  autoclose: true,
  clearBtn: true
});
```

This jQuery code is inside a `$(document).ready()` function in an external JavaScript file, which is included right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Any errors on the page? jQuery is included?

Comment: Yes, jquery is included and I don't get any errors.

Comment: What is the exact issue that you are facing ? Be more specific than saying it is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your JQuery you are targeting the id of the `<input/>` element. If you target the input's parent element, the bootstrap datepicker will work.

Try running this code snippet or check out this **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/dVbKZy)**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker-group").datepicker({
    format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
    todayHighlight: true,
    autoclose: true,
    clearBtn: true
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-group">
  <div id="datepicker-group" class="input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
    <input class="form-control" name="data" type="text" placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I saw the demo and it looks great , but it's not working in my case :/

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. I modified your solution a little bit

Comment: @eli I also ran into same problem. Could you share me your solution. 
Datepicker is working but the options I passed doesn't work

Comment: For me it was a matter of how you order your scripts. Make sure bootstrap-datepicker.* comes after the main bootstrap-*.* scipt/css files.

Answer (score 0):

To overcome the situation you need to use,

```
   $(document).ready(function () {      });
```

You need to target the input`s parent element. This makes date picker work fine.

JS Coding,

```
 <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#selectDate').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', // set date format as you prefer
                changeMonth: true, // if you want to change months
                changeYear: true,  // if you want to change years
                yearRange: "-50:+10",
                clickInput: true,

                onSelect: function (date) {
                    $('#selectName').val(date).attr('readonly', true); // if you want to make event fire after the date selection
                }

            });
        });

    </script>
```